# CrystalDecisions.Shared, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio

I am facing below error in my visual studio 2013 ,please help me if anyone know the solution .

```
 Error  10  Could not load file or assembly 'CrystalDecisions.Shared, 
Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304' or one of
 its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040).
```

Answer (score 0):

I will assume that when you are viewing the report you are using a custom app which uses CR 2008.  To deploy your app you will need two things:

1. The Runtimes
2. A valid Keycode

You can obtain the Runtimes here:

Runtime Downloads
CR 2008 msi: https://smpdl.sap-ag.de/~sapidp/012002523100005985862008E/cr120_redist_install.zip
CR 2008 click once: https://smpdl.sap-ag.de/~sapidp/012002523100005986302008E/cr120_clickonce.zip
CR 2008 msm: https://smpdl.sap-ag.de/~sapidp/012002523100005985842008E/cr120_mm.zip

You can also find these by going to here:
https://www.sdn.sap.com/irj/sdn/businessobjects-downloads

and selecting "Crystal Reports", ".NET", and "Utility"

I'm not sure if your eval keycode will work to deploy - but even if it does, the application will eventually stop working when the eval period runs out.  If you want it to keep working, you will need to purchase a permanent keycode.

From SAP Community